# Crystal Reports - Can I reference a field/value from my sub-report in my main report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm building a delivery note for our company. In the main report I have one SQL query, and in the sub-report, I have the order at line level (items ordered, quantity and price).

I've populated a running total of the quantities*items to give me a 'sub-total' field.

What I want to be able to do though, in my main report is formulate a 'grand total' in my main report, which takes postage and discounts away from the sub total in the sub report.

I'm not sure if there's an easy way to do this though? I obviously can't see that value in my main report.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shared variable in both subreport and main report.

Create a formula in the subreport:

```
shared numbervar total;
total := {#YourRunningTotalField};
```

Put the formula where the value is "ready". Maybe the subreport footer section.

Create a formula in the main report:

```
shared numbervar total;
total;
```

Put this formula somewhere after the subreport.

It would work in some scenarios, give it a try.